# What explains the different treatment of special characters in regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

Testing in Chrome 10 Developer Tools console:

```
> str = "\t";
  " "
> JSON.stringify(str)
  ""\t""
> str.replace(/\t/g,"\\t")
  "\t"
```

All good. The regular expression was able replicate part of the `JSON.stringify` behavior and identify the tab character.

Now let's swap out `\t` for `\b` throughout:

```
> str = "\b";
  ""
> JSON.stringify(str)
  ""\b""
> str.replace(/\b/g,"\\b")
  ""
```

In this case `replace` couldn't find the backspace character.

So, my esteemed SO colleagues, could someone lend me a clue and account for the difference in behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The escape sequences in regular expressions are not identical to the ones in string literals. In a regular expression, `\b` matches a word boundary. `\t` happens to be the same in regular expressions and string literals.

MDC has a [fairly good writeup of these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp), although of course there's nothing like going to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Comment: It seems obvious when you put it like that. The next question will have to be, how do I modify the regex to find and replace the backslash in the JavaScript string?

Comment: @Jim: The re escape sequence for a backslash is the same as it is in a string literal: Two backslashes: \\. Or if you meant *backspace*, you'd either have to use a hex escape (`\x08`) or Unicode escape (`\u0008`), or pass a string into the `RegExp` constructor (which I recommend avoiding, it gets very confusing very fast): `new RegExp("\\\b")` That creates a string containing a backslash followed by a backspace, which is then passed into the `RegExp` constructor. The `RegExp` sees the backslash and treats the next character (the backspace) literally. You see how it can get confusing.

Comment: T.J you are a star.. `str.replace(/\x08/g,"\\b")` delivers the goods.